# Insert block of text within variable at specific line number

Tags: bash

I am grabbing the contents of https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ using curl and asigning it to a bash variable. I want to insert this block of text into a file at a specific line number - 10

```
#!/bin/bash
salts=$(curl -s https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)
sed -i '10i '"$salts"'' myfile.php
```

however I keep getting the error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 102: extra characters after command

I think there maybe carriage return chars in the returned payload using curl but i'm not sure. I have tried using `tr` to replace them with `\n` but am unsure how to use it in this situation.

I have looked at multiple existing [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702677/how-to-insert-multiple-lines-with-sed) but I cannot get them to work in my situation. I don't have to use sed for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using awk

```
awk -v "s=$salts" 'NR==10{print s} 1' file
```

---

you could also combine head and tail

```
echo -e "$( head -9 file )\n$salts\n$( tail -n +10 file )"
```

boh of them seem to work with your variable that contains a lot of special characters.

Comment: Thanks, I actually went with a variant of the splitting and concatenation in the end